# Unity new Input-System and double jumping local multiplayer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, local, multiplayer

So I have some trouble using the new Input System on a game I'm currently working on.
The game is going to be some type of an Smash game and I already had implemented double jump with the old Input System and it worked but now I've changed it to the new one and I can just jump one time in Air again I know it must be some kind of an easy fix problem but im a beginner and I don't really understand the new I- System. Here's my Code:
I would really appreciate if you could help me out with this and eventually I can learn something of ur comment. (Btw. sorry for my english I'm not native lol)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed;
public float jumpForce;
public float moveInput;
public float checkRadius;

private int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

private bool facingRight = true;
private bool isGrounded;

public Transform groundCheck;

public LayerMask whatIsGround;

private Vector2 movementInput = Vector2.zero;
private bool jumped = false;


//OnMove Input to later set as Event in Input Manager
public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    movementInput = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}

//OnJump Input to later set as Event in Input Manager
public void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
{
    jumped = context.action.triggered;
}

//start
private void Start()
{
    extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    //check if isGrounded
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, 
 whatIsGround);

   
    moveInput = movementInput.x;

    //Move Right/Left relative to moveInput Value (-1 till 1)
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

    //rotate Player Sprite relative to a / d Input
    if(facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
    {
        Flip();
    } 
    else if(facingRight == true && moveInput <0)
    {
        Flip();
    }
}

private void Update()
{
    // if grounded set extra jumps u can take to a preset value 
    if(isGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }

    //if extrajumps is equal to 0 & player tries to jump and is grounded add upwards velocity
    if (extraJumps == 0 && jumped && isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }

    //subtract extra jump -1 and "jump"
    else if (extraJumps > 0 && jumped)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        extraJumps--;
    }

}

//rotate player
void Flip()
{
    facingRight = !facingRight;

    transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
}
```

}

[image: Here you can see my Input Manager Settings]

Comment: Maybe if you inverse the order condition (Check first jump before extra jump)

Comment: @vernou thank u for ur reply, but I just tested it and it did not work :|

Comment: I think really the mistake is apply the extra jump before the first jump, because the extra jump is executed first and the first jump never executed because the character isn't longer on the ground. Maybe you can add some comments to help us to understand the code.

Comment: @vernou I've added some comments for u to understand the code a little better hopefully u understand it now and no thats not the mistake as u can see I changed the code a little bit to match ur suggestion but it still does not work as excpected

Comment: What is the value of `extraJumpsValue`?

Comment: @vernou extraJumpsValue = 1 or 2 or 3...

Comment: @vernou I dont really understand what u want me to do to fix this issue

Comment: See my answer, I think you need in the condition to first jump remove this part `extraJumps == 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the condition to execute the first jump :

```
//When isGrouded then extraJumps equal 1 (in the case extraJumpsValue is 1)
if(isGrounded == true)
{
    extraJumps = 1;
}
//The next condition is always false
//Because when isGrouded then extraJumps is never 0
if (isGrounded == true && extraJumps == 0 && /*Some other condition*/)
...
```

I don't untertand why `extraJumps` is checked to do the first jump. I think you can remove this operand :

```cs
if (/*extraJumps == 0 &&*/ jumped && isGrounded == true)
{
    rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
}
```

Full code :

```cs
private void Update()
{
    // if grounded set extra jumps u can take to a preset value 
    if(isGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }

    //if player tries to jump and is grounded add upwards velocity
    if (jumped && isGrounded == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
    }
    //subtract extra jump -1 and "jump"
    else if (extraJumps > 0 && jumped)
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * jumpForce;
        extraJumps--;
    }
}
```